# an html color generated from a serial number to differentiate individual devices

Tags: javascript, embedded

Our clients have more than one of our web-enabled devices different only in serial number and IP address.

Clients are making mistakes when configuring several devices in a row because the individual web applications look too much alike and devices that work just fine have been returned because of client copy and paste mistakes.

It would be therefore very useful to differentiate the web applications with an easy-to-spot color in the web page header that would be different for each device.

The serial number is available to JavaScript and I was thinking that it would be nice to generate a unique color from that in JavaScript. That way each device would have a different color dot or geometric figure in each page header and be easier to differentiate.

I wrote JavaScript code that works:

```
function ChangeColor(mySerialNumber) 
{
    var i = 0;    
    var asciinum;  
    var numberstring = '';  
    for(i=0; i < mySerialNumber.length; i++)  
    {  
        asciinum = mySerialNumber.charCodeAt(i);  
        numberstring += (asciinum).toString();  
    }  

    if(numberstring.length < 9)  
    {  
        while(numberstring.length < 9)  
        {  
            numberstring = '9' + numberstring; // prepend  
        }  
    }  
    else  
    {  
         numberstring = numberstring.substring((numberstring.length -10),(numberstring.length -1));  
    }  

    newcolorcode = 'rgb(' + numberstring.substring(1,3) + ',';  
    newcolorcode = newcolorcode + numberstring.substring(4,6) + ',';  
    newcolorcode = newcolorcode + numberstring.substring(7,9) + ')';  

    alert('numberstring is ' + numberstring + ' and new color code is ' + newcolorcode);  

    colorme.style.backgroundColor = newcolorcode;  
}
```

Our serial numbers are sequential and look something like this:

677-026A, 677-027A, 677-028A etc.

So the generated colors are too close, and look too much alike.

Does anyone have a suggestion on improving the color span? I can't use a rand function because the color must remain identical on each web page of a given machine?

Thanks,
Bert

Comment: Those that are colorblind would not benefit from this extra layer of product enhancement. Before I read the part of the colors being too close is what was going through my mind. Hum, how about something else? Does this device have a LED that can be triggered or some type of power-cycle that would indicate it's "synced" to the program?

Comment: If you have a given set and there won't be any more serial numbers, you can just individually configure each one. Also, with the colourblindness issue, you should consider maybe outputting a unique "name" identifier for the device rather than a coloured dot.

Comment: Also, colors can fade quickly or appear different under certain lighting. Here's a different method to consider: QR Code's on the devices. Most mobile phones have apps that can read these codes and there are many [**Online QR Code Generators**](http://scan.me/qr-code-generator/) to use. Even webcams can read these codes too.

Comment: How about just displaying the least significant digit(s) of the serial number in different colors. Similar to resistor colors http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electronic_color_code 0-Black, 1-Brown, 2-Red, 3-Orange, 4-Yellow, 5-Green, 6-Blue, 7-Violet, 8-Gray, 9-White.

Answer (score 0):

This was resolved by adding decorative dots in a corner of the screen and allowing the user to change the color using the JavaScript Color Picker by Jan Odvarko

http://jscolor.com

On color selection, a JavaScript confirm asks the user if he wants to keep this color. If yes, an Ajax call persists the choice on the server side.

Works great.

Thanks all!